# How can I create a data base management system?

Tags: database, database-management

I have to create a data base management system as a project for the school but I don't know how to. It doesn't have to be very sophisticated. Is there any tutorial that shows how to do it? And, what would be the most appropriate language to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to actually *build* a database engine?  Or do you need to *use* a database engine to create a database that you write a program to use?

Without knowing exactly what you're after, for the latter, I'd recommend you get ahold of the MAMP (on Mac) or WAMP (on Windows) stacks.  this gives you Apache, MySql, and PHP on top of your favorite OS.  Following google threads on those topics should lead you to plenty of examples.

If you have to actually build a database engine... well, here's another SO question that might help: [Simple Database Implementation for Educational Purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241002/simple-database-implementation-for-educational-purpose).  Also, you might search through Github for open source examples.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this [repository](https://github.com/cstack/db_tutorial):
Prerequisites :

- Good understanding of algorithms & dynamic data structures like trees - B-trees.. (it's all about structuring data and handling it using optimized algorithms's implementation)
- Proficiency with C programming language ( pointers , structures-unions-typedef..) .